# No visible interface for selector error but declared in header?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement this method:

```
- (IBAction)createNewMap:(id)sender {
UIAlertController *alert = [[UIAlertController alloc] initWithTitle:@"No network connection"
                                                message:@"You must be connected to the internet to use this app."
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
}
```

In the header file I declared: UIAlertController *alert;

However I get a no visible interface for selector error? Why is that?

Comment: Can you please share the error screenshot?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/o6Jhh

Comment: You just get confused with alert controller for alert view. check this [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller)

Comment: I did use UIAlertController. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"No network connection" message:@"You must be connected to the internet to use this app." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

    }]];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: This code presents the AlertView, You're using the initWithTitle method which does not exist in UIAlertController Class, Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You got "No visible interface for selector error"
Because UIAlertController does not have *initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles* method in its class; It is available in UIAlertView class.

Actual implementation of UIAlertView [which is deprecated in iOS 9.0];

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No network connection"
                                                    message:@"You must be connected to the internet to use this app."]
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

To perform action when button is clicked, conforms to UIAlertViewDelegate protocol:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

& implement this delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // the user clicked OK
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        // do something here...
    }
}
```

You can use UIAlertController;

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"No network connection" 
                            message:@"You must be connected to the internet to use this app." 
                     preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" 
                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
                                                   //perform Action   }]];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated. Useless response.

Comment: Ya.. its deprecated! you should using UIAlertController :) @konyv12

Comment: UIAlertController do not have initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles method which you are trying to use! thats why i showed you implementation of both concerned alert's. hope that you understand :) @konyv12